# ASP.net 5 Web API modules section in Web.config

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I would like to add the following to Web.config of a Web api created in asp.net 5.
modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"

This was working fine in my Web api which was not asp.net 5. In asp.net where to add this?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no more `web.config` in ASP.NET 5.

In fact there is no more modules. The old pipeline is no more. To be honest... it look similar but it's not the same framework as before.

I would highly recommend that you [start by reading](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/) a bit on the new framework.

There's also a series that's called [ASP.NET Monsters](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/aspnetmonsters) that deep dive into it. You should take a look since it looks you are starting from scratch.